# error: cannot convert value of type 'TreeNode.TreeNode?' to expected argument type 'prog.TreeNode?' in solution.swift in Leetcode

Tags: swift, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to solve one basic question on the tree traversal problem in a swift in leetcode. I am not getting my error spot in the code.

Question: Given the root of a binary tree, return the preorder traversal of its node's values.

Input: root = [1,null,2,3]
Output: [1,2,3]

Input: root = []
Output: []

Input: root = [1]
Output: [1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkeL9.png this is a snapshot of question.
here is my solution:

```js
 public class TreeNode {
     public var val: Int
     public var left: TreeNode?
     public var right: TreeNode?
     public init() { self.val = 0; self.left = nil; self.right = nil; }
     public init(_ val: Int) { self.val = val; self.left = nil; self.right = nil; }
     public init(_ val: Int, _ left: TreeNode?, _ right: TreeNode?) {
         self.val = val
         self.left = left
         self.right = right
     }
 }

class Solution {
    var result = [Int]()
    func preorderTraversal(_ root: TreeNode?) -> [Int] {
        if let temRt = root as? TreeNode {
            traversal(temRt)
        }
        return result
    }
    
    func traversal(_ root: TreeNode?) {
        if let tempRoot = root as? TreeNode {
            result.append(tempRoot.val)
            traversal(tempRoot.left)
            traversal(tempRoot.right)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the input: [1,null,2,3]

And Result I am getting:
Line 49: Char 48: error: cannot convert value of type 'TreeNode.TreeNode?' to expected argument type 'prog.TreeNode?' in solution.swift
let ret = Solution().preorderTraversal(param_1)

However I tried this solution on playground it was giving correct result by giving the input such that:

let p = TreeNode(1, nil, TreeNode(2, TreeNode(3,nil,nil), nil))

print(Solution().preorderTraversal(p)) //[1, 2, 3]

Please help me out to get the correct result, to understand how here input is passing to the function and what is the mistake here.

Comment: What is `prog`?

Comment: Please also post the code where you use the class.

Comment: @RickyMo here call done by the online compiler leetCode, here "func preorderTraversal(_ root: TreeNode?) -> [Int]" is given predefine empty body function, under which we have to write our own logic and return the result.

Comment: @George
I have no idea, what the "prog" is and how the compiler calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

You’d have to delete your “duplicate” definition of the TreeNode and just assume that the environment already defines it, as shown in the comments.